Alternative for Nested If in PowerApps
I'm new to PowerApps, and I need help in simplifying a code. Would appreciate if someone could help, and thanks in advance. The code that I have now is working under nested if, but its too long. So I need an alternative solution.
So in short, I have 3 comboboxes, and based on selection of values from that comboboxes, I am launching a filtered result url, that opens my sharepoint list with the filtered result. So now I want to add more conditions, so then the number of possible combinations would also increase, and hence nested if would be too long. My code right now is:
Launch(
    "example.com" & If(
        IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
        "",
        If(
            !IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
            "&FilterField1=A1&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box1.Selected.DisplayName),
            If(
                IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
                "&FilterField1=A2&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box2.Selected.DisplayName),
                If(
                    IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
                    "&FilterField1=A3&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
                    If(
                        !IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
                        "&FilterField1=A1&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box1.Selected.DisplayName) & "&FilterField2=A2&FilterValue2=" & EncodeUrl(box2.Selected.DisplayName),
                        If(
                            !IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
                            "&FilterField1=A1&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box1.Selected.DisplayName) & "&FilterField2=A3&FilterValue2=" & EncodeUrl(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
                            If(
                                IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
                                "&FilterField1=A2&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box2.Selected.DisplayName) & "&FilterField2=A3&FilterValue2=" & EncodeUrl(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
                                If(
                                    !IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
                                    "&FilterField1=A1&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box1.Selected.DisplayName) & "&FilterField2=A2&FilterValue2=" & EncodeUrl(box2.Selected.DisplayName) & "&FilterField3=A3&FilterValue3=" & EncodeUrl(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
                                    ""
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

I don't know what else to try, I tried using Switch, but I am making some errors.

Before simplifying the code, there one small thing you can do to make the current code look a little cleaner: you don't need to have multiple nested 'If' statements, one of them is enough:
Launch(
    "example.com" &
    If(
        IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
            "",
        !IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
            "&FilterField1=A1&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box1.Selected.DisplayName),
        IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
            "&FilterField1=A2&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box2.Selected.DisplayName),
        IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
            "&FilterField1=A3&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
        !IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
            "&FilterField1=A1&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box1.Selected.DisplayName) & "&FilterField2=A2&FilterValue2=" & EncodeUrl(box2.Selected.DisplayName),
        !IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
            "&FilterField1=A1&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box1.Selected.DisplayName) & "&FilterField2=A3&FilterValue2=" & EncodeUrl(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
        IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
            "&FilterField1=A2&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box2.Selected.DisplayName) & "&FilterField2=A3&FilterValue2=" & EncodeUrl(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
        !IsBlank(box1.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box2.Selected.DisplayName) && !IsBlank(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
            "&FilterField1=A1&FilterValue1=" & EncodeUrl(box1.Selected.DisplayName) & "&FilterField2=A2&FilterValue2=" & EncodeUrl(box2.Selected.DisplayName) & "&FilterField3=A3&FilterValue3=" & EncodeUrl(box3.Selected.DisplayName),
        ""
    )
)

Now to the simplification: your logic needs to combine a few values by '&' if their corresponding boxes are selected. In this case you can use the Concat function, after filtering the selections for non-empty ones, something similar to the expression below:
Launch(
    "example.com" &
    With(
        {
            valuesToFilter: Filter(
                [
                    { Field: "A1", Value: box1.Selected.DisplayName },
                    { Field: "A2", Value: box2.Selected.DisplayName },
                    { Field: "A3", Value: box3.Selected.DisplayName }
                ],
                Not IsBlank(Value)
            )
        },
        Concat(
            Sequence(CountRows(valuesToFilter)),
            $"&FilterField{Value}={Index(valuesToFilter, Value).Field}&{EncodeUrl(Index(valuesToFilter, Value).Value}"
        )
    )
)


Thanks a lot for your help. I've made some minor modifications to the solution you provided, and its working. You are a life saver.

I have a doubt. Is it possible to do a search like in different field names from just one box value. Say I want to search for box1.Selected.DisplayName in Field A1, A2, A3. So the search should function like, it should search if box1 value is either in field A1, or in A2, or in A3. Is this possible. Any help from you is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
